# how to calculate the average closing price for the last 12 hours

Tags: average, pine-script

Thsi is my code to calculate the average closing price for ***the last 12 hours*** of a currency pair, in this case AUDCAD.

```
// 12 refers to last 12 hours
expr720 = ta.sma(close, 12)
audcad720 = request.security('AUDCAD', "60", expr720, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Is this correct pls?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What timeframe are you using this on?

Comment: I dont want to be tied to a timeframe, but would like it to give the same result on any timeframe, can this be done?

Comment: Anyone can help?